# Publicly available <lightning:recordViewForm with field of type Lookup does not provide options

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordviewform

I have a `<lightning:recordViewForm` in a custom lightning component with a `<lightning:outputField` which is mapped to a field of type `Lookup(CustomObject__c)`

The lightning component is on a **publicly** available Communities page, so therefore being accessed using the `guest` profile/user.

The `guest` profile/user has `read` and `view all` permissions for the Lookup object `CustomObject__c`

The `guest` profile/user has `read` and `edit` permissions on the lookup field.

The `<lightning:recordViewForm` and the `<lightning:outputField` display, but no options appear when I type in the lookup input box.

Why don't I get any options in the lookup field?

Comment: Did you configure global search dialogues in Lightning for CustomObject__c? Until you do, you're not going to see any lookup options in your form.

Comment: @crmprogdev how do I `configure global search dialogues in Lightning for CustomObject__c` ?

Comment: Go to Lightning Setup -> Objects -> MyCustomObject__c and you'll see the various settings that you need to configure on the LH Menu, including one for Search.

Comment: @crmprogdev Thanks for responding, but I was looking for something a little more specific that directions to all the settings for a custom object...

Comment: Again, all of the lookup dialogue settings appear once you click on Search from the LH menu column. There are about 5 of them that should be configured for an object. I don't know how much more specific I can be than that.

Comment: @crmprogdev thanks, but all those settings are setup fine, your suggestion was a dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected it was a permissions issue.

The `Lookup(CustomObject__c)` had a `Lookup Filter` which use a field the `guest` user did not have `read` permissions over.